# Prove that for all $y\ge0$ there exists a unique real number $x$ such that $xe^x=y$.

Tags: calculus, integration

(a) Prove that for all $y \ge 0,$ there exists a unique real number $x$ such that $xe^{x}=y$

(b) By part (a), for $y \ge 0,$ we can let $f(y)$ be the unique real number such that
$f(y)e^{f(y)} = y$

Find

$\int_0^e f(x)\, dx.$

I am not sure how to solve this but I have tried several things. I have tried replacing e^x with g(x) and looking at the relationship between functions f and g (I got f(y)g(f(y))=y. This doesn't seem to really help me though. I tried finding g'(x) as well, and I am still not sure how to approach the first part of the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding (a): What happens if you let $x=0$ and $x\to\infty$? And what can you say about continuity and monotonicity in $x$? Can you use these insights to prove the claim?

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 2):

Hint for part (a): If you can prove that $g(x) = xe^x$ is monotonically increasing, what would it mean? What is the range of the function?

Hint for part (b): What is $f$ in simple terms? Or rather, what is $f(g(x))$ where $g$ is defined as in part (a)? Can you use that to somehow use substitution for the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=x\cdot e^x$.

To solve (a) we have to know:

- the value $g(0)$ and $g(\infty)$ (i.e. limit in infinity)
- the sign of $g'(x)$ for $x>0$.
- The mean value theorem.

To solve (b) one can draw the graph of $g$ in the rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,e]$ and observe that $\int_0^ef(x)dx+\int_0^1g(x)dx = \mathrm{area}([0,1]\times [0,e])$.